# Trouble Implementing Auth0 No authentication handlers are registered error with ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, auth0

Hello I am getting the following error when trying to Login. On ASP.NET Core MVC app.

“InvalidOperationException: No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?”

[image]

Below is my startup and account controller class

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.ConfigureSameSiteNoneCookies();

            services.AddAuth0WebAppAuthentication(options => {
                options.Domain = Configuration["Auth0:Domain"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
            });

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
}
```

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            var authenticationProperties = new LoginAuthenticationPropertiesBuilder()
                 .WithRedirectUri(returnUrl)
                 .Build();

            await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
        }

        [Authorize]
        public async Task Logout()
        {
            var authenticationProperties = new LogoutAuthenticationPropertiesBuilder()
                 // Indicate here where Auth0 should redirect the user after a logout.
                 // Note that the resulting absolute Uri must be whitelisted in 
                 .WithRedirectUri(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))
                 .Build();

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Profile()
        {
            return View(new UserProfileViewModel()
            {
                //Name = User.Identity.Name,
                EmailAddress = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value,
                //ProfileImage = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "picture")?.Value
            });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is just a helper action to enable you to easily see all claims related to a user. It helps when debugging your
        /// application to see the in claims populated from the Auth0 ID Token
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public IActionResult Claims()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult AccessDenied()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

I also tried open id connect to solve the issue but I get the same error.

Here is the start up code using OpenID Connect

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            

            // Add authentication services
            services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options => {
                // Set the authority to your Auth0 domain
                options.Authority = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";

                // Configure the Auth0 Client ID and Client Secret
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

                // Set response type to code
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;

                // Configure the scope
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");

                // Set the callback path, so Auth0 will call back to http://localhost:3000/callback
                // Also ensure that you have added the URL as an Allowed Callback URL in your Auth0 dashboard
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");

                // Configure the Claims Issuer to be Auth0
                options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";

                // Saves tokens to the AuthenticationProperties
                options.SaveTokens = true;

                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    // handle the logout redirection 
                    OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
                    {
                        var logoutUri = $"https://{Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/v2/logout?client_id={Configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]}";

                        var postLogoutUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
                        {
                            if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                            {
                                // transform to absolute
                                var request = context.Request;
                                postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                            }
                            logoutUri += $"&returnTo={Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
                        }

                        context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
                        context.HandleResponse();

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            services.AddMvc()
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            // app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            /*app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name:"default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```